# AccordionItem title property is empty even though its set in kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to access title property of AccordionItem in python code, that is being set in kv file. The property is empty string even though it is correctly displayed in GUI.

Is there a way to access value of this property or am I missing something here?

kv file

```
<TableModifications>:
    accordion: accordion
    MDAccordion:
        id: accordion
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: None
        width: '240dp'
        TableAccordionItem:
            title:'Add' # I want to access this in python code
            icon: 'plus'
        TableAccordionItem:
            title:'Edit'
            icon: 'pencil'
        TableAccordionItem:
            title:'Remove'
            icon: 'delete'
```

python code

```
class TableModifications(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TableAccordionItem(MDAccordionItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TableAccordionItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.title) # this is empty, why?

    def add_widget(self, widget, *args):
        super(TableAccordionItem, self).add_widget(widget, *args)
        print(self.title) # this is empty, why?
```

Comment: If the answer below is correct, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use kivy's `ObjectProperty` that will magically bind to widgets in your kv. Also, if a widget has already been added to your widget tree in kv lang, then you don't need to add that widget again in python. `add_widget` is not a method you need to override. If you want to add a widget you do something like: `self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello"))`.

Example:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
    accord_1: accord_1
    accord_2: accord_2
    accord_3: accord_3
    Accordion:
        orientation: "vertical"
        AccordionItem:
            id: accord_1
            title: "Title 1"
            Label:
                text: "Accordion One Content."
        AccordionItem:
            id: accord_2
            title: "Title 2"
            Label:
                text: "Accordion Two Content."
        AccordionItem:
            id: accord_3
            title: "Title 3"
""")


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    accord_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    accord_2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    accord_3 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.accord_3.add_widget(Label(text="Accordion Three Content."))

        for ac in [self.accord_1, self.accord_2, self.accord_3]:
            print ac.title


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```